# Downloading json/show on site and delete by ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I have a app, and this is a local project, so in this app I have a table with data. So now I need to download and show in table in html json file (todo.json) by jQuery and AJAX and next can delete one or all objects in site and update and save in this json file (todo.json). I must do this in ajax by jquery. I search in Can somebody could help me?

```js
var todos = new Array();
var todo_index = 0;
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
    submitButton.onclick = getFormData;
    getTodoData();
}

function getTodoData() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "todo.json");
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE && this.status == 200) {
            if (this.responseText) { 
                parseTodoItems(this.responseText);
                addTodosToPage();
            }
            else {
                console.log("error");
            }
        }
    };
    request.send();
}

function parseTodoItems(todoJSON) {
    if (todoJSON == null || todoJSON.trim() == "") {
        return;
    }
    var todoArray = JSON.parse(todoJSON);
    if (todoArray.length == 0) {
        console.log("Error:empty array!");
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < todoArray.length; i++) {
        var todoItem = todoArray[i];
        todos.push(todoItem);
    }
}


function checkInputText(value, msg) {
    if (value == null || value == "") {
        alert(msg);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}        
function Todo(index, parts, item, dueDate) {
    this.index = index;
    this.parts = parts;
    this.item = item;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;

}
                    


function addTodosToPage() {
  var table = document.getElementById("todoList");
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var index = document.getElementById('index').value;
  var parts = document.getElementById('parts').value;
  var item = document.getElementById('item').value;
  var dueDate = document.getElementById('dueDate').value;

  tr.innerHTML = "<td>" + index + "</td><td>" + parts + "</td><td>" + item + "</td><td>" + dueDate + "</td>";
  table.appendChild(tr);


  todo_index++;


  tr.id = "todo-" + todo_index;

  var index = document.getElementById('index').value;
  var parts = document.getElementById('parts').value;
  var item = document.getElementById('item').value;
  var dueDate = document.getElementById('dueDate').value;

  tr.innerHTML = "\
  <td><input name='select-row' type='checkbox' value='" + todo_index + "'></td>\
  <td>" + index + "</td>\
  <td>" + parts + "</td>\
  <td>" + item + "</td>\
  <td>" + dueDate + "</td>\
  <td><button onclick='removeTodo(" + todo_index + ");'>x</button></td>";
  table.appendChild(tr);
}

function checkInputText(value, msg) {
    if (value == null || value == "") {
        alert(msg);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}        


function removeTodo(index) {

  var row = document.getElementById('todo-' + index);

  if (row) {

    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  }


  todo_index--;
}


function toggleSelection(checkbox) {

  var rowsToSelect = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=select-row]');

  for (var i = 0; i < rowsToSelect.length; i++) {

    rowsToSelect[i].checked = checkbox.checked;
  }
}


function removeSelectedTodos() {

  var rowsToRemove = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=select-row]:checked');

  for (var i = 0; i < rowsToRemove.length; i++) {

    removeTodo(rowsToRemove[i].value);
  }
}



function setselection(){
  var project = document.getElementById('todoList').value;
  document.cookie = 'todotabela=' + project;
}


function getselection(){
  var name = 'todotabela=';
  var x = document.cookie.split(';');
  var i = 0, c = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    c = x[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(selectedProject) === 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  } return '';
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th><input onchange="toggleSelection(this);" type='checkbox'></th>
      <th>Index</th>
      <th>parts</th>
      <th>item</th>
      <th>Data</th>

      <th><button onclick='removeSelectedTodos();'>x</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="todoList">
  </tbody>
</table>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="tableContainer">
      <label for="index">
        <select id="index" name="index"> 
          <option hidden="" >Index</option> 
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
      </label>
      <input placeholder="parts" type="number" id="parts" min="0" />
            <input placeholder="item" type="number" id="item" min="0" />
            <input type="date" id="dueDate"/>
     
           <br>
      <input type="button" id="submit" onclick="addTodosToPage()" value="Add"> 
      </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
  <script src="todo3.js"></script>
  <script src="data.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly at which point did you stuck? Receiving data, or displaying it, or so..

Comment: Receiving and displaying :(

Answer (score 0):

This example is too large for shor answer and I will show you how you can receive data using `XMLHttpRequest` object.

1. If you are writing app you should build reusable components, so Ichange your `getTodoData()`

   ```
   function request(method, url, data=null) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
       const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
       xhr.timeout = 2000;
       xhr.responseType = 'json'
       xhr.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
           if(xhr.readyState === 4){
               xhr.status === 200 ? resolve(xhr.response) : reject(xhr.status)
           }
       }
       xhr.ontimeout = () => reject('timeout');
       xhr.open(method, url, true);

       if(method.toString().toLowerCase() === 'get') {
           xhr.send(data)
       } else {
           xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
           xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
           xhr.send(data)
       }
     })
   }
   ```

And `request` is reusable component and you can make `GET, POST, PUT or DELETE` call to your api. Next we should code function to get data, for this reason I use introduced in ES7 async/await, but you can use common promises or even callback.

```
async function getTasks(){
    const task = await request('GET', 'todo.json') //in task constnt you should have your data
}
```

And example with promises:

```
function getTasks(){
    request('GET', 'todo.json').then(data => {
       console.log(data)
    }
}
```

Check whether your file path (todo.json) is correct

Comment: Thank you. But could you tell me how can i adopt it in my code? I'm newbie and I don't know everything. When I was change getTodoData() to your code nothing is changed. And i don't know what should i do with getTasks

Comment: My json.date is looks like [{"data":[{"index":false,"parts":false,"item":false,"dueDate":false},{"index":"1","parts":3,"item":1"dueDate":01-01-2019}]}]

Comment: Thanks, but i think so it isn't this, becouse file is importing and path is showing in console.log. Maybe I just something bad adding or some previous method is overwritten. Now my todo3.js looks like this - https://jsfiddle.net/efo0L9q1/

Comment: Now i have todo3.js:26 XHR finished loading: GET "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json-formatter/0.7.0/json-formatter.js". If that's what you mean

Comment: Look, https://jsfiddle.net/cbr86aoz/1/ here I load json file and everything works good. I am sure that you have incorrect file path

Comment: I don't know what i was doing bad, i delete php function, make a many change and now when I add your file from github i have error: Uncaught (in promise) 0 I don't know what I am doing bad. Checking with xampp and single, and still nothing.